# Plotting with Pandas on a laptop with 16GB RAM

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am working with a dataset in a Python jupyter IPython notebook that is 1.7GB.  I read in the `.csv` that I am working with using `pd.read_csv`, and my RAM usage shoots up to about 7GB.

When I tried to plot the time series of one of my columns from the dataset, my RAM shot up to nearly 16GB.  I was worried about the performance of my laptop, so I decided to interrupt the kernel.

My question is two-fold:

- If I let the cell run, would the plot have eventually shown up?  Or, is it unable to plot my chart because it reached it's RAM limit?
- My data is a time-series of second-by-second data over the course of a month that contains mostly zeroes.  Should I remove these zeroes from the data, and would it make it easier to plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It will eventually show up. Even if it uses more than 16gb it will use the pagefile to get more virtual memory. It's called paging. It is an important part of memory implementations in modern operating systems, using secondary storage to let programs exceed the size of available physical memory. When a computer runs out of RAM, the operating system (OS) will move pages of memory over to the computer's hard disk to free up RAM for other processes. This ensures that the operating system will never run out of memory and crash.
   For more information: http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/memory-paging

[image]

2. It depends on whether you need or not the zeroes. It may be easier to plot or to visualize depending on the amount of data added by them.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  So, I don't need the zeroes, because it would be assumed that if there is no data for that time-stamp, then it would be zero.

Comment: It's probably better to remove then. Please, accept this if you feel like it is the correct answer.

Comment: So just to clarify for my own knowledge - what is going on when my memory hits 16GB?  Is it trying to plot in pieces?

Comment: It's called paging. It is an important part of memory implementations in modern operating systems, using secondary storage to let programs exceed the size of available physical memory. When a computer runs out of RAM, the operating system (OS) will move pages of memory over to the computer's hard disk to free up RAM for other processes. This ensures that the operating system will never run out of memory and crash.